# PHP MySQL: Display records NOT in table 2, 3, 4 and 5

Tags: mysql

I need to display records in table 1 where serialnumber is NOT IN table 2, 3, 4, and 5.

I currently figured out a way to display the records for table 1 where serialnumber is NOT IN table 2 with the following:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE serialnumber NOT IN 
(
  SELECT serialnumber
  FROM table2
)";
```

I just need to add the other tables to this query. I tried adding `AND` 
but it doesn't work. Please assist.

Comment: can you define "doesn't work"? That isn't much to go on and if you're checking for errors or not. The table definitions/schema/values are unknown, and what results you're getting now as opposed to the desired results.

Comment: notice the upvotes on my above comment? 2 people agreed so far, but you're not responding. I stay in questions longer than I should in trying to lend a helping hand, but you seem to not want to respond to it. So, in turn, you have to either wait till somebody can guess what the real problem is, or you need to debug your code. Good luck, I will not be staying here any much longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add union ALL clause:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE serialnumber NOT IN 
(
    SELECT serialnumber FROM table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT serialnumber FROM table3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT serialnumber FROM table4
...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of subqueries, you can do a **more efficient** `Left Join`. we can simply do a left join from `table1` to the rest of the tables (`table1` being left table for all of them). Now, `serialnumber` values which do not exist in the other table(s), will have `null` value post Join. So, we can simply use `Where serialnumber IS NULL` condition to filter out:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.serialnumber = t1.serialnumber 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t3 ON t3.serialnumber = t1.serialnumber 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t4 ON t4.serialnumber = t1.serialnumber 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t5 ON t5.serialnumber = t1.serialnumber 
WHERE t2.serialnumber IS NULL AND 
      t3.serialnumber IS NULL AND 
      t4.serialnumber IS NULL AND 
      t5.serialnumber IS NULL
```